# How to use dynamic passport SAML stratagey?

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, passport.js, saml, passport-saml

I am trying to implement SAML for google and okta for the different enterprises. Now, I have multiple entry points for that.

```
 passport.use(
    "saml",
    new SamlStrategy(
        {
            protocol: "https://",
            entryPoint: "entry url", // SSO URL (Step 2)
            issuer: "issuer link", // Entity ID (Step 4)
            path: "ACS URL parth", // ACS URL path (Step 4)
        },
        async function (profile, done) {
             {function body}
        }
    )
);
```

now, how can I set issuer URL dynamic every time as per user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that you want you pass dynamic entry point or can say multiple. you can achieve by **Configure strategy for multiple providers** in passport-sml , there is one function called **getSamlOptions** here you can write your code to fetch dynamic data from database

Ex:

```
passport.use("dynmaic-sml", new MultiSamlStrategy(
    {
        passReqToCallback: true, // makes req available in callback
        getSamlOptions: async function (request, done) {

            // get sso config from db and pass 

            return done(null, config);
            
        }
    },
    function (req, profile, done) {
        // logic after response
    })
);
```